# IEnumWbemClassObject::Next method not working

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, hard-drive

i am trying to vendor specifc attribute from this WMI class MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData(HDD SMART information).
Here is the used code :

```
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery( L"WQL", L"SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData",
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
      while (pEnumerator)
   {
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
            //**I am getting an issue here the method Next() returns hr=-2147217405 **

    if(0 == uReturn || FAILED(hr))
      break;
         //do smoething
     }
```

i need to know why Next() is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i figured out the solution.I should run visual studio as **Administrator**

Comment: I don't think that's your problem.  I've used that method without running as admin.  Have you made sure to initialize COM before making any WMI calls?

Comment: yes i deed that.
-2147217405 == 0x80041003 == WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED